# Extract data from Python set

Tags: python, nltk

I have this python set:

```
>>> print (x)
[(0, Synset('basic.n.01'), Synset('cry.v.02')), 
 (3, Synset('base.n.01'), Synset('help.v.04'))]
```

I want to parse it to list or dictionary like this:

```
{"value": 0, "keyword1": "basic",  "keyword2": "cry"} 
{"value": 3, "keyword1": "base",  "keyword2": "help"}
```

Comment: Where does the third entry in the second dictionary come from? How is it related to the input data? Why do you choose 'base' as the lemma for Synset('base.n.01') and 'cry' for Synset('cry.v.02')? They have other lemmas, too.

Comment: @DYZ It was a mistake, edited the question

Comment: Where does "laugh" come from? How do you choose a lemma name for each synset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your data structure to a dictionary, but you need an auxiliary function:

```
def prepare(item):
    return item[0],item[1].lemma_names()[0], item[2].lemma_names()[0]

keys = "value", "keyword1", "keyword2"
[dict(zip(keys, prepare(item))) for item in x]
```

Comment: Yes I want the first one only